# ¿Cómo envío los datos de un textbox aún estos estando deshabilitados?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox

Este es mi caso:

Tengo un formulario con varios textbox.Unos cuantos texbox tengo que rellenarlos manualmente y los otros textbox no, ya que estos se llenan automáticamente al hacer un calculo en otra parte de la misma pagina.
Cuando les pongo la propiedad Enabled=True, se llenan con los datos calculados, pero cuando intento enviar todos los datos del formulario hacia la base de datos, no se registran ninguno.

¿Por qué los quiero tener deshabilitados? Porque no quiero que el usuario los modifique directamente, ya que ellos toman el resultado del calculo que mencioné.

Comment: Anadir su codigo tambien, por favor

Comment: Supongo que estas hablando de formulario web. Yo lo que hago es añadir los mismos campos, con el mismo name pero de tipo hidden, de esta forma los muestras y los envia

Answer (score 0):

puedes poner en

```
readonly = true
```